# Unable to transfer values from instance object into instance array of parent class

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I have a JS class inside which I am instantiating a goog.net.XhrIo object. Now I can get all the stuff  I need from that JS variable, the problem is whenever I try to assign values to an instance variable of the "parent" class, I get an undefined error. I assume this is a scoping problem, but I don't know how to deal with it.
I am using the Google Closure Library.
The code can be found at:

[MAIN JS FILE](http://www.niuzly.com/ajax/niuzly.main.js)

I am trying to store all the result of the POST request inside a this.items object/array. The line number is 270. If you are looking at this in your browser, search for "console.log(this.mainView);" and it will take you straight to where the problem is.

```
goog.net.XhrIo.send(this.URL+'/action.url.php', function(e){
    var items = new Object();
    items = e.target.getResponseJson();
    for(var x in items)
    {
        var currentName;
        var currentCat;
        if(items.hasOwnProperty(x))
        {
            currentName = items[x].name;
            currentCat = items[x].categories;
        }
        var x = goog.dom.createDom('div', {
        }, currentName, currentCat);
        console.log(this.mainView);
    }
    return e;
},'POST', 'action=getUserData');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind the handler to the object with [`goog.bind`](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_base.js.html#goog.bind):

```
goog.net.XhrIo.send(this.URL+'/action.url.php', goog.bind( function(e){
    var items = new Object();
    items = e.target.getResponseJson();
    for(var x in items)
    {
        var currentName;
        var currentCat;
        if(items.hasOwnProperty(x))
        {
            currentName = items[x].name;
            currentCat = items[x].categories;
        }
        var x = goog.dom.createDom('div', {
        }, currentName, currentCat);
        console.log(this.mainView);
    }
    return e;
}, this),'POST', 'action=getUserData');
```

Comment: life saver thank you! I forgot you can preserve the meaning of this with goog.bind. Even tried the XhrIo instance instead of utility function, still won't let you scope the listener as normal listeners. Thanks for the tip!